# How to make implicit conversion constructor call over 2 class in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, implicit-conversion

Here is the test code:

```
class A 
{
public:
    A(const int& i){}
};

class B
{
public:
    B(const A& a) {};
};


int main() 
{
    B b = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

It comes to error: `"No viable conversion from int to B"`.

It's obviously that `int` can be converted to `B` through being converted to `A`. But it seems that C++ does not search the constructor inherited tree.

Note that B is not inherited from A.

Is there any way to make it possible without adding a `int` constructor for B manually?

Comment: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/qNSKhvsen95LyoIu

Comment: @Danh It's amazing. How does this happen?

Comment: Direct Initialization will call a constructor, if no match found, it will try to find at most 1 implicit conversion

Comment: `B b = {1};` should work, too

Comment: @Danh So if there is a `C` constructed by `B`, `C c = {1};` should not work, right?

Comment: Yes, if you mean C constructor accept a B

Comment: For yes, I meant _should not work_

Comment: C++ will not search for an arbitrarily long conversion sequence.